# Adapter pattern for Gem that uses multiple composed classes?

Tags: ruby

I'm using the Axlsx gem (https://github.com/randym/axlsx) for generating excel files. I want to refactor my code so that I have a wrapper around the gem just in case I want to switch gems.

Going through this reminds me of the Adapter design pattern. However, there are just so many objects nested underneath the main Package object that I am getting confused as to how to actual create an adapter for it. Ex:

1. You create a `Package` object
2. You access the `Workbook` within this `Package` objet
3. You access the `Sheet` from the `Workbook` object, and vice versa

Here are some of my classes:

```
class ReportGenerator::Base
  ...
  def create_workbook
    ...
    @package   = Axlsx::Package.new <---------------------------
    @workbook  = @package.workbook <---------------------------
    @workbook.use_shared_strings = true
  end


class Sheet::Base
  def initialize(workbook, question, options = {})
    ...
    @sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(:name => sheet_name) <---------------------------
  end

  def styles
    @styles ||= {
      "title"                 => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:sz => 20, :b => true, :alignment => { :wrap_text => true }),
      "bold"                  => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:b => true),
      "header"                => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:fg_color => "FFFFFF", :bg_color => "ff3333", :sz => 12, :b => true, :alignment => {:horizontal => :center}, :border => {:style => :thin, :color => "FFFFFF"}),
      "subheader"             => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:fg_color  => "FFFFFF", :bg_color => "ff3333", :sz => 12, :b => true, :alignment => {:horizontal => :center}),
      "subheader_border_left" => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:fg_color  => "FFFFFF", :bg_color => "ff3333", :sz => 12, :b => true, :alignment => {:horizontal => :center}, :border => {:style => :thin, :color => "FFFFFF", :edges => [:left]}),
      "blue_link"             => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:fg_color => '0000FF'),
      "wrap_text"             => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:alignment => { :wrap_text => true, :horizontal => :left }),
      "percentage"            => @sheet.workbook.styles.add_style(:format_code => "0.00%")
    }
  end
```

Here's my first stab:

```
class ExcelWriter
  def initialize
    @package = Axlsx::Package.new
  end

  def workbook
    @package.workbook
  end

  # starting to feel like it's not doable within one class..?

end
```

There are so many classes involved that it feels like I can't wrap everything into one adapter? Or maybe I'm doing it wrong? Any tips would be welcomed.

Comment: The first stab doesn't make much sense either, since you've already tied it to Axlsx. A wrapper "just in case" doesn't seem like a good ROI the way it sounds in your question. And in order to write a reasonable wrapper you'd probably want to investigate another gem's approach, methods, classes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on what you're actually using and not on existing infrastracture of Axlsx gem. This way you may combine work of several Axlsx objects into 1 method call.

I don't know what you're actually using, so it's hard for me to say which objects do you need.